# How to make circular play/pause audio player button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
        <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
             <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor"
                volume="1.0">
            </audio>
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
         <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
            <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
                volume="1.0">
                 </audio>
            </span>
```

And this javascript:

```
const audioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
const buttonToStopAllAudios = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')

const getAudioElementFromButton = buttonElement =>
  buttonElement.querySelector('audio')

const stopAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
  // Pause the audio
  getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).pause()

  // Update element classes
  buttonElement.classList.add('fa-play')
  buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-pause')
}

const playAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
  // Pause the audio
  getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).play()

  // Update element classes
  buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-play')
  buttonElement.classList.add('fa-pause')
}

audioButtons.forEach(audioButton => {
  audioButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // I get this first because I have to pause all the audios before doing anything, so I have to know it this audio was paused or not
    const audioElement = getAudioElementFromButton(audioButton)
    const audioIsPaused = audioElement.paused

    // Stop all audios before starting this one
    audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)

    audioIsPaused
      ? playAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Play if it's paused
      : stopAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Pause if it's playing
  })
})

buttonToStopAllAudios.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)
})
```

Upon running, it forms two play/pause audio players that are live streaming radio stations. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bhs6tysg/5/).

How can I make these audio players look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2L0T.jpg)?

I'm not sure if the URL of `href` needs to be changed here.

Comment: Use [border-radius:50%;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) or edit an image using background transparency. I would do the latter.

Comment: @PHPglue Hi, Could you please elaborate how can I use it exactly with my code? I'm actually still a beginner and I have built this code with lots of hit and trial and help. Thanks :)

Comment: @PHPglue the latter? That's stupid when you can use font awesome and a border radius.

Comment: @timusR did you search the internet first? Because I don't think you did or else you wouldn't have asked such a stupid question that has been asked and answered thousands of times before.

Comment: @Darkrum Like I said I'm a beginner. And I know that people have asked here before very well but I don't know how some parts of their code are working. Therefore I cannot just copy and paste it. That's why I asked to elaborate specifically on my code. No need to be rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either change your icon with font-awesome, check the index [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery), or you can use javascript and css to create an animated icon.

If you decide to create an icon yourself, check this [example](https://codepen.io/Kirtle/pen/RMYxxE) on codepen. Keep in mind that I used jquery there and you'll need to import it to your project. If you have any questions feel free to ask but I'd recommend you to do a little research before asking here because you can easily change your icons since you are using font-awesome which is an icon library included in bootstrap.

```
<div class="control play trigger-audio">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor" volume="1.0"></audio>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="control play trigger-audio">
  <span class="left"></span>
  <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925" volume="1.0"></audio>
  <span class="right"></span>
</div>

<style>
.control {
    border: 11.2px solid #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 28px;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control,
.control .left,
.control .right,
.control:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: border 0.4s, width 0.4s, height 0.4s, margin 0.4s;
    transition-tiomig-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.control:before {
    content: "";
    height: 112px;
}

.control.pause .left,
.control.pause .right {
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 36.96px solid #333;
    border-top: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
    height: 96.992px;
}

.control.pause .left {
    border-right: 22.4px solid transparent;
}

.control.play .left {
    margin-left: 18.66666667px;
    border-left: 48.496px solid #333;
    border-top: 28px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    height: 56px;
}

.control.play .right {
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 48.496px solid #333;
    border-top: 28px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
}

.control:hover {
    border-color: #000;
}

.control:hover .left,
.control:hover .right {
    border-left-color: #000;
}

</style>

<script>
const audioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
const buttonToStopAllAudios = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')

const getAudioElementFromButton = buttonElement =>
    buttonElement.querySelector('audio')

const stopAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
    // Pause the audio
    getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).pause()

    // Update element classes
    buttonElement.classList.add('fa-play')
    buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-pause')
}

const playAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
    // Pause the audio
    getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).play()

    // Update element classes
    buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-play')
    buttonElement.classList.add('fa-pause')
}

audioButtons.forEach(audioButton => {
    audioButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // I get this first because I have to pause all the audios before doing anything, so I have to know it this audio was paused or not
        const audioElement = getAudioElementFromButton(audioButton)
        const audioIsPaused = audioElement.paused

        // Stop all audios before starting this one
        audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)

        audioIsPaused
            ?
            playAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Play if it's paused
            :
            stopAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Pause if it's playing
    })
})

buttonToStopAllAudios.addEventListener('click', () => {
    audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)
})

$('.control').on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pause play');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        $('.control').toggleClass('pause play');
    }
});

$('.control').on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pause play');
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 32) {
        $('.control').toggleClass('pause play');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the example. Actually, I'm building it on Wix website and they don't support Jquery yet so I have to import it in their HTML editor. I tried something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lafq2ydq/4/ using google hosted jquery but it doesn't seem to work and the play/pause audio players lose their transition. Could you tell me what needs to be fixed?

Comment: Try importing jquery 2.1.3. You can have it [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js)

Comment: Thanks that worked :D But now there is one thing that's happening I can't seem to figure out. When playing the second audio player while the first one is already playing, the streaming of the first audio player does stop but its sign is stuck on the play transition. Here is it jsfiddle.net/ezqbz4k1/7

Answer (score 0):

You can add this simple code to start customizing your button:

```
.trigger-audio {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 11px;
}

.trigger-audio:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then you can modify color on click, smooth effect or transition.